# How to know the JavaScript event source on function scope?

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

### Question

Is it possible to know if the function was fired by a user event or an async event (like callback) without having the original event parameter?

### Background

I'm trying to determine the event source in a deeper function call which doesn't know who was the original event trigger.

I have to know that in order to call a popup or redirection login system. But this function is called from many places, so I can't pass the event parameter in all callers.

**Important**: *I'm not able to pass parameters to the final function*. `b('timer')` is not allowed.

e.g.:

```
  <a onclick="b()" >call</a>
   <script>
 
   function a(){
      b();
   }

   function b(){
      final();
   }

   function final(){
      //Is there something like this caller.event.source ?
      console.log(this.caller.event.source)
   }
   
   setTimeout(a,1000);
```

In that example, I'm trying to get `source == 'timer'` or `'onclick'`, or any other information to determine which is the event origin.

### Update

Based on basilikun approach I've implemented this solution:

```
function final(){
    var callerFunction = arguments.callee.caller,
    evtArg = callerFunction.arguments[0];
    while(callerFunction.caller){
        callerFunction = callerFunction.caller;
        if (callerFunction.arguments[0]) {
            evtArg = callerFunction.arguments[0];
        }
    }
    console.log(evtArg&&evtArg.type?'event fired by user':'event async');
}
```

This is the [finddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpAxX/3/)

Any other approach?

Comment: why can't you pass arguments to `b`?

Comment: What did you define `a` for?

Comment: so `b("timer")` is not possible but would it be possible to pass something at least to the first function that is called by the event (to `a`)?

Comment: @Asad: sorry, I updated my sample, now a() is called.

Comment: @user1737909: I can't pass arguments to b because in my real code, b is call from docens of places, and many of them I don manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you can at least pass "timer" in the very first function `a`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpAxX/1/)

```
<a onclick="a()" >call</a>

<script>

function a(){
    b();
}

function b(){
    final();
}

function final(){
    var callerFunction = arguments.callee.caller;
    var evtArg = callerFunction.arguments[0];
    while (callerFunction.caller !== null) {
        callerFunction = callerFunction.caller;
        if (callerFunction.arguments[0]) {
            evtArg = callerFunction.arguments[0];
        }
    }
    console.log(evtArg);
}

setTimeout(function(){a("timer")}, 100);

</script>
```

This will get you the very last possible first argument in the chain of function calls. So if you use "normal" events it will give you the event object. And if you use a timeout it will give you whatever you pass to the first function.

Note that this solution also uses `arguments.callee.caller` which is supposed to be slow and not supported everywhere. And as robC already mentioned, it is not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to throw an exception in the innermost function, catch it, and use the exception to determine the call stack.

The details of how to obtain the call stack are vendor specific (`e.stack` in FF, `e.message` in Opera, sketchy function body parsing in IE and Safari), but a reasonably robust implementation exists on [eriwen.com](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/js-stack-trace/).

This, at least, is what I can make out from the short snippet posted on that page. Do note that this has evolved into a [full blown project on Github](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace), and as such is likely to be more reliable and feature packed than the 50 line snippet on that page.

In your example, you would use:

```
function b(){
    final();
}
function final(){
   var trace = printStackTrace();
   //output trace
}


//This would be attached as the click handler for the anchor
function anchorHandler(){
   b();
}
setTimeout(function timerCallback(){
    b();
}, 1000);
```

Depending on whether `timerCallback` or `anchorHandler` are in the trace, you know what event triggered the function call.

Comment: _“and use the exception to determine the call stack”_ – this makes me shiver a bit …

Comment: God that sounds sketchy as hell.

Comment: very cleaver!, however I found a simpler solution for my issue. Thanxs!

Answer (score 1):

You could use arguments.callee.caller to access the function object and attach an expando... not sure if this is possible for your situation. Note that this won't work in strict mode as arguments.callee.caller is deprecated.

```
<a onclick="b()" >call</a>

<script>

   function a(){
      b.calledByA = true;
      b();
   }

   function b(){
      final();
   }

   function final(){
      var caller = arguments.callee.caller;
      console.log(caller.calledByA);
      caller.calledByA = null;
   }

   setTimeout(a, 1000);

</script>
```

Comment: arguments.callee.caller was also my first thought, but it still won't give him the info by what kind of event `a` was called (timeout).

Comment: It could be done by deduction, if programmatic calls always set expandos on b.